# R e SQL - Como fazer um JOIN de um data.frame no R com uma tabela no SQL?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, join

Possuo uma tabela no PostgreSQL que contém a coluna "cnae".

Também tenho um `data.frame` no R com as colunas "cnae" e "descricao".

Preciso subir a coluna "descricao" para a tabela no PostgreSQL combinando pela "cnae". Tipo um `left_join()`.

Não encontro como fazer isso. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Tenho esse `data.frame` em um arquvio .csv. Mas também não sei como subir para o PostgreSQL e fazer direto por lá.

Comment: Para mandr uma tabela para o banco basta `dbWriteTable(con, "nome_que_tera_no_banco", objeto_no_R)`